# Display image from flask send_file (ajax response) into the image tag

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

How do I display the image from a flask send_file ajax response

**HTML file**

---

```
<button class="button" id="start">Start</button>

    <script>
        //start button click event

        $('#start').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/capture',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "image/jpg",
                success: function(result) {
                    document.getElementById('frame').src = 'data:image/jpg,' + result;
                }
            });
        });
```

**flask**

```
@app.route('/capture')
def capture_api():
    ...
    image_binary = img.read()

    return send_file(io.BytesIO(image_binary),
                     mimetype='image/jpeg',
                     as_attachment=True,
                     attachment_filename='%s.jpg' % "capture")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the encoding, at both the backend and frontend.

at flask

```
image = b64encode(image_binary).decode("utf-8")
return jsonify({'status': True, 'image': image})
```

**html**

```
document.getElementById('frame').src = 'data:;base64,' + result['image'];
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to encode your image data as base64 and add it to an image element in your dom.

I've created a sample application in repl.it: https://repl.it/@MichaelAnckaert/Flask-Playground

Here's a sample Flask application:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response
import base64
app = Flask('app')

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
  return render_template('image.html')


@app.route('/capture')
def capture_api():
  with open("house-thumbs-up.gif", "rb") as f:
    image_binary = f.read()

    response = make_response(base64.b64encode(image_binary))
    response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'image/gif')
    response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='image.gif')
    return response

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

And the corresponding HTML template:

```
<img id="image">

<button class="button" id="start">Start</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"     integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  let button = document.getElementById("start")
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://luminoustwincase--five-nine.repl.co/capture',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "image/jpg",
        success: function(result) {
          document.getElementById('image').src = 'data:image/gif;base64,' + result;
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use bytes to draw an image, you should add `base64` to src tag.

```js
document.getElementById('frame').src = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + result;
```